# Recibir un array en PHP proveniente de AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, array

Buen dia,

estoy usando la libreria jsxlsx la cual me lee un archivo de excel que esta en el servidor, este puede contener varias lineas de datos pues todos los dias se subira un archivo distinto, para el ejemplo uso solo 5 lineas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en esta parte la libreria me guarda todo en un array y al hacer el console.log(lectura excel) me muestra el array perfectamente

```
var lectura_excel=XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet,{raw:true});
console.log(lectura_excel);
```

[image: Array leido del excel]

luego lo envio al PHP por ajax de la siguiente manera

```
$.ajax({
  data: lectura_excel,
  url: "../php/actualizar_puntos.php",
  cache: false,
  dataType: "json",
  type: "POST",
  beforeSend: function()
  {
     //hacer algo antes de enviar
  },
  success: function(respuesta)
  {
    //hacer algo al recibir respuesta
  },   
});
```

hasta aquí se que el array lectura_excel esta bien pues lo veo en la consola como muestro en la imagen, lo que no logro es leerlo en el PHP, lo que intento aquí es leer el campo nomb_terc_ de la posicion 0 la cual viene sienddo "10986825" para entender como leer el array y luego si recorrerlos todos y hacer algo con ellos allá, y si no es mucho pedir me pudieran ayudar a leer el array en un foreach o un for

```php
<?php
  $valor = $_POST["lectura_excel[0]['nomb_terc_']"];
  echo json_encode($valor);
?>
```

Gracias!

Comment: haz un `print_r` a `$_POST` y pega el resultado que te da para ver como te lo está regresando en PHP al mandarlo

Comment: @Sr1871 hice esto print_r($_POST["lectura_excel[0]['nomb_terc_']"]); pero no muestra nada

Comment: @GabrielUribeGomez Es posible que la dirección no apunte al archivo. *../php/actualizar_puntos.php* apunta a un directorio hermano del directorio en que se ecuentra *baselink*. ¿Ya verificaste que el árbol de directorios corresponda?

Comment: @quevedo si, he cambiado ciertas columnas en el excel y ya lo puedo ver en el php